# TypeLoadException with Mono 2.11.4 (Mono 2.10.8.1 works fine)

Tags: mono, ubuntu-12.04, typeloadexception

I compiled [a Mono project](https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare) and it crashes on the newest version of Mono.

SparkleShare works fine on Mono 2.10.8.1 (default on latest Ubuntu):

```
$ /usr/bin/mono --version | grep version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2)
$ /usr/bin/mono bin/SparkleShare.exe
16:16:11 | Auth | Imported key [...]
```

But not on Mono 2.11.4 ([built](http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_From_Git) from latest Git):

```
$ /usr/local/bin/mono --version | grep version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.11.4 (master/31e9b80 Tue Aug 21 15:21:41 JST 2012)
$ /usr/local/bin/mono bin/SparkleShare.exe
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'SparkleShare.SparkleUI' from assembly 'SparkleShare, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'SparkleShare.SparkleUI' from assembly 'SparkleShare, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Does this `TypeLoadException` look familiar to anyone?
Any tip on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works with Mono 2.10.8.1 and not Mono 2.11.4 it's clearly a bug, indeed a regression.

You should file it in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Mono 2.11.x series are still previews (unstable) versions, prior to the next 2.12.x stable series (the convention is to use odd numbers for unstable releases).

Comment: That would have been the best thing to do, indeed. Actually, I just compiled Mono 2.10.8.1, and the problem still happens, so it is a problem with my building environment, not a problem with 2.11.4, sorry for the false alert!

Comment: What was the build issue? I am having a similar problem.